# Create dynamic form fields based on a dropdown , jquery ,php

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a dropdown in my form which actually helps generate mysql db queries on the fly based on the query type .
 e.g if my querytype in the dropdown in fetchYourDetails , then a text box will appear in the form which will ask for my name . Once , I enter my name and click on *generate* , it will frame the query and run it in the background php.

Like this I have around 4/5 query types and it's likely to increase in the future. Here I have a problem with my current implementation .

What I'm presently using is : a form where I have the dropdown and all the parameter fields (hidden) to start off with . Now, with the onchange() function in my js , I will show some specific parameter rows based on the dropdown option selected and hide the rest.

so here's how my HTML code looks like :

```
<form>
   <table>
      <tr id='dropdown'>
         <td>
            <select id='select_options' onchange ="javascript:updateCustomQueryFields();">
               <option value='getyourdetails'></option>
               <option value='getyourbikedetails'></option>
               <!-- so on -->
            </select>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style='display:none'>
         <td>
            <!-- one field -->
            <!-- create the generate option -->
         </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style='display:none'>
         <td>
            <!-- one field -->
            <!-- create the generate option -->
         </td>
      </tr>
      <!-- so on -->
   </table>
</form>
```

and my onchange function looks like :

```
function updateCustomQueryFields()
{
    val=$('#select_options').val();

    //hideallfieldsfirst

    if(val=='getyourdetails')
    {
        //show one field
    }
    else if(val=='getyourbikedetails')
    {
        //show one field
    }
}
```

so far so good , now , when I click on **generate option** , it will execute the query and fetch the data from the db and display it in a results div below the form.

So, at the time of displaying results also, I have to hide some fields and display others in the view , based on the parameters set in the controller.
So the series of **if-else statements** are likely to increase there as well , when we add some more parameters .

**So what I want is some mechanism by which we will generate the parameter fields on the fly , e.g , if the query type is 'getyourdetails' , only the name field should be created and rest all fields should be removed in the backend onchange function .**

So how can that be achieved using jquery ? and will it be a proper methodology to implement the scenario what I want  ? I have to keep in mind the propulating of my parameter fields once the call returns from the controller after fetching the results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understood your question but at least my knowledge about your request says for making these kinds of forms it's better to use `remove` and `append` functions of jQuery. You can create any control dynamically and set them under control by the ID that you set for them. It's easy as drinking a glass of water!

[Remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove), [Append](http://api.jquery.com/append)

Correct me if my answer is wrong.